# How to change color in a basic Paint program using java .awt

Tags: java, awt

so im working on this simple painting program that records mouse events such as entering exiting, dragging,etc... the program records all these points and stores it in an array list of "lines"( A class i defined for this task) then the program paints the list to the screen. my question is how should i go about changing the color of the stuff im painting with out changing the color of the ones i have already painted any help is appreciated thank you.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MyNewDrawFrame extends Frame{

     public MyNewDrawFrame(){
        setSize(500,500);
        setTitle("Drawing is fun");
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        MyNewDrawPanel mdp = new MyNewDrawPanel();
        add(mdp);
        setVisible(true);
     }
     public static void main(String[] args){
         MyNewDrawFrame mdf = new MyNewDrawFrame();
     }
}

class MyNewDrawPanel extends DoubleBuffer implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener,ActionListener{

    int lastX=0, lastY=0;
    ArrayList<Line>lines;
    Color color;
    Button red, green, black, blue;

    public MyNewDrawPanel() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        red = new Button("Red");
        green = new Button("Green");
        blue = new Button("Blue");
        black = new Button("Black");
        red.addActionListener(this);
        green.addActionListener(this);
        blue.addActionListener(this);
        black.addActionListener(this);
        red.setBackground(Color.red);
        green.setBackground(Color.green);
        blue.setBackground(Color.blue);
        black.setBackground(Color.black);
        Panel p = new Panel();
        p.add(red);
        p.add(green);
        p.add(blue);
        p.add(black);
        add(p, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        lines = new ArrayList<Line>();
        setBackground(Color.white);
        color = Color.black;
        setForeground(color);
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }
    public Color getColor(){
        return color;
    }
    public void setColor(Color color){
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me){}
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me){}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me){
    }
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me){
        record(me.getX(), me.getY());
    }
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me){
        record(me.getX(), me.getY());
    }
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me){}
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me){
        int x = me.getX();
        int y = me.getY();
        lines.add(new Line(lastX, lastY, x, y));
        record(x, y);
        repaint();
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        for(Line line: lines){
                g.setColor(color);
                g.drawLine(line.getStartX(), line.getStartY(), line.getEndX(), line.getEndY());
        }
    }
    public void record(int x, int y) {
        lastX = x;
        lastY = y;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

        if (ae.getSource() == red){
            setColor(Color.red);
        }
        else if (ae.getSource() == blue){
            setColor(Color.blue);
        }
        else if (ae.getSource() == green){
            setColor(Color.green);
        }
        else if (ae.getSource() == black){
            setColor(Color.black);
        }
    }
}

class Line{

    int startx, starty, endx, endy;


    public Line(){}
    public Line(int startx, int starty, int endx, int endy){
        setStartX(startx);
        setStartY(starty);
        setEndX(endx);
        setEndY(endy);

    }
    public void setStartX(int startx){
        this.startx = startx;
    }
    public void setStartY(int starty){
        this.starty = starty;
    }
    public void setEndX(int endx){
        this.endx = endx;
    }
    public void setEndY(int endy){
        this.endy = endy;
    }
    public int getStartX(){
        return startx;
    }
    public int getStartY(){
        return starty;
    }
    public int getEndX(){
        return endx;
    }
    public int getEndY(){
        return endy;
    }
}

    import java.awt.*;

public class DoubleBuffer extends Panel{

    private int bufferWidth;
    private int bufferHeight;
    private Image bufferImage;
    private Graphics bufferGraphics;




    public DoubleBuffer(){

        super();
    }

    public void update(Graphics g){
            paintBuffer(g);
    }

    public void paintBuffer(Graphics g){
        //    checks the buffersize with the current panelsize
        //    or initialises the image with the first paint
    if(bufferWidth!=getSize().width || bufferHeight!=getSize().height ||bufferImage==null || bufferGraphics==null)
            resetBuffer();
        if(bufferGraphics!=null){
            //this clears the offscreen image, not the onscreen one
            bufferGraphics.clearRect(0,0,bufferWidth,bufferHeight);

            //calls the paintbuffer method with
            //the offscreen graphics as a param
            paint(bufferGraphics);

            //we finaly paint the offscreen image onto the onscreen image
            g.drawImage(bufferImage,0,0,this);
        }

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){

            //in classes extended from this one, add something to paint here!
            //always remember, g is the offscreen graphics
    }
    private void resetBuffer(){
        // always keep track of the image size
        bufferWidth=getSize().width;
        bufferHeight=getSize().height;

        //    clean up the previous image
        if(bufferGraphics!=null){
            bufferGraphics.dispose();
            bufferGraphics=null;
        }
        if(bufferImage!=null){
            bufferImage.flush();
            bufferImage=null;
        }
        System.gc();

        //    create the new image with the size of the panel
        bufferImage=createImage(bufferWidth,bufferHeight);
        bufferGraphics=bufferImage.getGraphics();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Line` class should store color. Fill it in `mouseDragged` and use like this

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    for(Line line: lines){
            g.setColor(line.getColor());
            g.drawLine(line.getStartX(), line.getStartY(), line.getEndX(), line.getEndY());
    }
}
```